# Make <li> list per item of array within an object VueJs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I was trying to find the way in the docs, but I couldn't. In Vue JS, I have this `data` structure:

```js
recipes: [ 
  {
    name: string, 
    ingredients: [array],
    link: string
  } 
]
```

I can make a `v-for` and get my app to show the name, the link and the ingredients. However, I cannot find the way to loop through the ingredients array and make it show like a list.

This is how it looks like now:

[image: 1]

And I want it to be like:

- tomatoes
- bread
- garlic

So, basically I need to know how to ask for an iteration of items in an array within an object.

This is my component's code:

```
<!-- This creates a card per recipe -->
<template >
  <div v-if="cardView" class="recipes container section">
    <div class="row">
      <div v-for="recipe in recipes" class="col s12 m6">
        <div class="card blue-grey darken-1">
          <div class="card-content white-text">
            <h1 class="card-title">{{recipe.name}}</h1>
            <h2>Ingredients</h2>
            <ul>
              <li v-for="(recipe,index) in recipes" :key="index">{{recipe.ingredients}}</li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
              <li v-for="recipe in recipes">{{recipe.meals}}</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="card-action">
            <a href="#">Full Recipe</a>
            <a href="#">Add to Week Menu</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { db } from "@/firebase/config";

export default {
  name: "RecipesCards",
  data() {
    return {
      recipes: []
    };
  },
  methods: {},

  created() {
    db.collection("Recipes")
      .get()
      .then(snapshot => {
        snapshot.forEach(doc => {
          let recipe = doc.data();
          recipe.id = doc.id;
          this.recipes.push(recipe);
          console.log(this.recipes);
        });
      });
  },

  props: ["cardView"]
};
</script>
```

Comment: I think you just do a v-for for the ingredients like <li v-for="ingredients in  recipe.ingredients" ..... </li>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Makes sense, cause you're itterating over the same array and returning ingredients values, and value of each object is an array.

Since your list is inside recipes loop, you may iterate over the array of each object of that array, so your v-for of a list should look like this

```
<li v-for="(ingredient, index) in recipe.ingredients" :key="index"> 
{{ingredient}}</li>
```

Another approach - make component for each card and return ingredients as an array through computed properties.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation. It does work perfectly. Just wanted to point out that finally the v-for should be placed inside de <ul> so that the <li> creates one line per ingredient.

Comment: That's true, depends on which DOM element you want to create. Try to think outside of html doc doing tihs tasks. Basically, what you had was

`array.forEach(el => {
  // show el.name of that array
  array.forEach(el => {
    //show element of that array
  }
}`

And what you wanted was:

`array.forEach(el => {
  // show el.name of that array
  el.forEach(el2 => {
    //show el2.something of that array
  }
}`

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood correctly then you want to change this:

```html
<li v-for="(recipe,index) in recipes" :key="index">{{recipe.ingredients}}</li>
```

to this:

```html
<li v-for="(ingredient, index) in recipe.ingredients" :key="index">{{ ingredient }}</li>
```

Here `recipe` is defined by the surrounding `v-for` on the `div`, which you already have.